# How is it posible to set a var property from within a function defined in that var?

Tags: javascript

I have a question regarding definitions of factories in AngularJS. I am unsure if this is a Javascript doubt or AngularJS, but I believe it's Angular.

Say I have a factory definition like this:

```
angular.module('myApp.services')
  .factory('User', function($http) { // injectables go here
    var backendUrl = "http://localhost:3000";
    var service = {
      // our factory definition
      user: {},
      setName: function(newName) {
        service.user['name'] = newName;
      },
      setEmail: function(newEmail) {
        service.user['email'] = newEmail;
      },
      save: function() {
        return $http.post(backendUrl + '/users', {
      user: service.user
      });
   }
  };
return service;
});
```

How is it possible that the function setName is able to set `service.user['email']`, if `service` is actually defining `setName` itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is basic javascript. Forget about the factory for a minute, only consider definition of `service`.

```
var service = {
    //service will have an empty user js object
    user: {},

    //a key setName with the value as a function
    //which sets a key value pair in user defined above 
    //service = { user: {name: 'Tony'} }
    setName: function(newName) {
      service.user['name'] = newName;
    },

    //a key setEmail with the value as a function
    //which sets a key value pair in user defined above 
    //(consider setName has been called already)
    //service = { user: {name: 'Tony', email: 'tony@stark.com'} }
    setEmail: function(newEmail) {
      service.user['email'] = newEmail;
    },

    //a key save with the value as a function
    //which saves
    save: function() {
      //return something from a call mimicing $http.post
      //return $http.post(backendUrl + '/users', { user: service.user });
    }
}
```

Then, return or use `service` which has become an API by itself.

Check out dev tool console for log in this [<kbd>**FIDDLE**</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/M4nFX/1/)

Comment: That's interesting. But, My question is, how is it possible that the setName, which is defined by service, has access to service itself? How does JS manage to do that? Is because service is defined before setName?

Comment: Each API element in a `function()`, which means, only when you call the API method the underlying code will be executed. By the time you call `setName()` on service, service is already defined (see my jsfiddle). Makes sense? `service.user['name']` is equivalent to `this.user['name']`. Plus, the major factor here is **scope** in JS. JS is not blocked scope so you can access service inside the api method itself.

Answer (score 0):

`setName` function is going to be called by some other code like this,

`User.setName("newname ");` when this is called the `service` already defined and it's about setting new value to a property.

and you could use `this` keyword to make the code more meaningful,

```
 setName: function(newName) {
      this.user['name'] = newName;
 }
```

I see one issue with your code, even though you have defined `setName` function you have the `user` variable is accessible to  outside of the factory,now you can do like this as well,

```
User.user['name'] = newName;
```

I think what you need to do is make `user` a private variable,

```
angular.module('myApp.services')
  .factory('User', function($http) { // injectables go here
    var backendUrl = "http://localhost:3000";
    var user={};
    var service = {
    // our factory definition

    setName: function(newName) {
      user['name'] = newName;
    },
    setEmail: function(newEmail) {
      user['email'] = newEmail;
    },
    getUser:function(){
       return user;
    }, 
    save: function() {
      return $http.post(backendUrl + '/users', {
          user: service.user
    });
 }
};
return service;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing is a behavior of JavaScript's **closures**.

Basically, a function has access to the variables outside of the function's scope.  If those variables change, it's changed everywhere.

1. When the functions are created, `service` is still `undefined`
2. The functions create a **closure** around the `service` variable
3. `service` is then assigned to be the object
4. All the functions are now pointing to the `service` object

Here's a way to visualize this:

```
var service = null;
var getService = function() { return service; };

service = 5;
getService(); // returns 5

service = "service can change";
getService(); // returns "service can change";
```